# Missing git commits over http but available over ssh

Tags: git

I am using a git repository for several months and everything works like a charm.

To integrate git into [Target Process](http://www.targetprocess.com/) I had to make the repository available through http.
The apache setup works (the document root is the directory where all repositories lie and currently no htaccess).

When cloning the repository over HTTP it works but it is an old state (there are no commits in the log for the last two days) - no matter what branch has been selected.

I cloned with TortoiseGit and Windows Git Bash - all the same.
Tried also to copy the whole git repository and chmod'ed to 0777 in order to exclude right issues but it is the same.

Over SSH the commits are all available.

What is the reason for that and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-server-info.html which is prerequisite for http server.